# The finite union of bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded (Is this proof right?)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In order to show that it is bounded I need to show that it is contained in some neighbourhood of $\mathbb{R}$. Here is my proof:

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{ A_1,\ldots,A_n \}$ a finite collection of bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$, since each $A_i$ ($i=1,...,n$) is bounded and because of the greatest lower bound axiom, it has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound, let $p=\max(\sup A_1,\ldots,\sup A_n)$ and $q=\min(\inf A_1,\ldots,\inf A_n)$, define $y = \frac{p+q}{2}, \ \alpha = \frac{p-q}{2} $. Let $x \in \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j$, then $x \in A_k$ for at least one $k$ (where $1\leqslant k \leqslant n$). Let $\epsilon > 0$, consider the neighbourhood $B(y,\alpha) = (q-\epsilon, p+ \epsilon)$, then: $q-\epsilon < \inf A_k \leqslant x \leqslant \sup A_k < p + \epsilon$, so that $x \in B(y, \alpha)$, then $A_k \subset B(y, \alpha), \ \forall k=1,\ldots,n, \ \forall \epsilon >0$ (since $x$ was arbitrary). Therefore the finite union of bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded.

I think this successfully proves the theorem, but I am not 100% sure, can some one check my proof? Thanks!!

Comment: What is a neighborhood of $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following arguments is easier:
Let $R=\max\{|\sup A_i|,|\inf A_i|:i=1,\dots,n\}+1>0$.
Then $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n\subset B(R,0)$, hence bounded.

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need the greatest lower bound axiom. E.g., the claim is true also about subsets of $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb Z$ or in fact for *any* metric space $(X,d)$:

We may assume wlog that all $A_i$ are non-empty, so fix an element $a_i\in A_i$.
For each $A_i$, we know that it is bounded, i.e., that there exists $r_i\in \Bbb R$ with $d(x,y)<r_i$ for all $x,y\in A_i$. Then with $r:=2\max\{\,r_i\mid 1\le i\le n\,\}+\max\{\,d(a_i,a_j)\mid 1\le i<j\le n\,\}$ one readily verified that $d(x,y)<r$ for all  $x,y\in A_1\cup \cdots \cup A_n$.